# html <img> showing different size of some images

Tags: html, image

I have some images and I am using this class for every  tag to set same height and width-

> .imgsize{
>               height:80px;
>               width:80px
>           }

The issue is some of the images are not rendering according to the size. here is the layout of those images

- [image]

as you can see the right side image is showing according to the size in CSS class but the 1st and 2nd is a bit smaller. However, when I refresh the page I see first 2 images as the same size as third one( but just for a few seconds till the page is loading).
When I gave custom size to the 2 images the difference was 15 px in height and width.

> height="95" width="95" style="margin-top:-6px"

but then it showed like its the same size as 3rd one. I don't understand the reason why is it behaving this way.

```
<div class="row">
    <img src="Images/icons/images/背景图-（03_42.png" />
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
        <img src="Images/中控首页按钮/首页按钮-默认状态/控制页面_106.png" 
            id="CurtainOpen" class="imgclick imgsize" /></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
        <img src="Images/中控首页按钮/首页按钮-默认状态/控制页面_108.png" 
            id="CurtainClose" class="imgclick imgsize"/></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
        <img src="Images/详细页图标/全部按钮/控制全页面-默认状态/控制页面_110.png" 
            id="CurtainStop" class="imgclick imgsize" /></div>
</div>
```

Is something wrong with images or with code.?
Any advice will be appreciated.

**Edit:**

This is the screenshot while the page was loading - this is how the image looks the exact same size as one another for just... maybe 2 seconds only -

[image]

Comment: Try adding `img {display: inline-block}`

Comment: @Justinas I am sorry but it didnt change anything

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for your help guys. The issue is resolved now and Its same as I started to think , it was not rendering the same size because those images were very small in size than other images on my page. those images were from 93-99 px in size and so they might not be showing according to the css Class(80px). I made those people to change the image size and make it bigger originally. Now its looking same..
But still I am in doubt as 80px was small from its original size then also it didnt show correct.

Answer (score -1):

sorry to writing this on answer, because i don't have enough reputation to write a comment.

anyway,

from your question in the html tag you get height="95" width="95" style="margin-top:-6px" inside.

so, try type it in your css

```
.imgsize{ height:80px !important; width:80px !important; }
```

it ignores any post styles unless you reload or change class mapping the css.

Comment: This is also not working. And I think  if any other class was changing its layout then it should have probably impacted same on other images as I only have different src and IdNames. styling is same. I have checked, their actual size are same approx, but they are showing different on web page.But now I think it might be something wrong with those few images.

Comment: can you check one more thing? try clear cache (ex : open the webpage in secret mode Chrome etc..) and see does it still showing same happens.

Comment: `!important` is **extra bad practice** and it means you done something wrong with your CSS code